# Rewriting an optimal control law in feed back form

Tags: matrices, optimization, dynamical-systems, optimal-control

We have a dynamical system:
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}&=Ax+Bu\\
x(0)&=x_{0}
\end{align*}
that is controllable. Given the cost function:
$$
J(u,t_{1})=\int_{0}^{t_{1}}u^{T}udt,\quad x(t_1)=0,
$$
it is known that the optimal control is $u^{*}=-B^{T}e^{A^{T}(t_{1}-t)}W(0,t_{1})^{-1}e^{At_{1}}x_{0}$. How can I show that we can write $u^{*}$ on the form:
$$
u^{*}=-B^{T}e^{A^{T}(t_{1}-t)}W(t,t_{1})^{-1}e^{A(t_{1}-t)}x(t).
$$
My attempted solution so far is the following.

Given the optimal control we rewrite:
\begin{align*}
u^{*}&=-B^{T}e^{A^{T}(t_{1}-t)}W(0,t_{1})^{-1}e^{At_{1}}x_{0}\\
&=-B^{T}e^{A^{T}(t_{1}-t)}W(0,t_{1})^{-1}e^{A(t_{1}-t)}e^{At}x_{0}\\
&=-B^{T}e^{A^{T}(t_{1}-t)}W(0,t_{1})^{-1}e^{A(t_{1}-t)}\left(x(t)-\int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)ds\right)\\
&=-B^{T}e^{A^{T}(t_{1}-t)}W(0,t_{1})^{-1}e^{A(t_{1}-t)}x(t)+B^{T}e^{A^{T}(t_{1}-t)}W(0,t_{1})^{-1}e^{A(t_{1}-t)}\int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)ds
\end{align*}
where I used that the solution to a system on the given form is:
$$
x(t)=e^{At}x_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)ds.
$$
The first term in my attempted solution looks close to the desired form but I am not sure how to continue from here, or if I am completely off.

Furthermore, a similar question to mine is posted here: [Linear Quadratic optimal control in feedback form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682284/linear-quadratic-optimal-control-in-feedback-form) but I do not know how to tie it together to my desired form.

Comment: For completeness, the Gramian matrix should also be given.